# Preencher a fórmula horizontalmente mas incrementar as referências da célula verticalmente

Tags: microsoft-excel, office-2013

Preciso preencher uma tabela com horizontalmente com referência a valores que estão na vertical de outra tabela

Na tabela horizontal estou fazendo o seguinte

```
='Tab 3x3'!G10
```

Só que quando arrasto para o lado ele incrementa a coluna e não a célula.
Precisaria que ele continuasse G11, G12.. e assim por diante.

Já tentei ancorar($) de todas as maneiras mas não adianta.
Também tentei utilizar o TRANSPOR  que até funcionou mas ficou uma bagunça, eu precisaria da referência mesmo como a formula acima.
Dei uma pesquisada também e achei um pessoal usando Offset, mas não consegui entender muito bem.

Alguma maneira fácil de fazer isso?

Comment: Olá Gabriel, você já tentou usar o `TRANSPOR` da forma como abaixo e não deu? Creio que se quiser a fórmula como citou terá de fazer manualmente... ou talvez, se explicar melhor a utilização posterior a qual é necessária ter a fórmula conforme citado, posso tentar te ajudar com outras fórmulas que retornarão o que é necessário. Talvez vinculando um `CORRESP` com `ÍNDICE`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar a função `TRANSPOR` que possui um pequeno segredo para funcionar.

Nos seguintes dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1. Selcione onde deseja ter os dados transpostos (vinculados) e digite a seguinte fórmula:

`=TRANSPOR(A1:A4)`

> Selecione a quantidade de células conforme sua origem ou a quantidade que deseja transpor.
>
> A matriz onde estão os dados no meu exemplo ficou `A1:A4`, onde estão os dados de origem conforme imagem de exemplo.

2. Pressione `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> É importante pressionar `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` e não somente `ENTER`.
>
> Notar que os dados ficam vinculados, se alterar a origem (`A1:A4` no meu exemplo) alterará também onde foi transposto.

Espero ter ajudado!

3. Se precisar da referência completa conforme citado na pergunta ao invés dos dados, poderá ter a referência (endereço) da célula cofnorme segue:

`=CÉL("endereço";ÍNDICE(Plan1!$A$1:$A$4;CORRESP(C1;Plan1!$A$1:$A$4)))`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que tem a fórmula `CORRESP` que busca da célula transposta o endereço de origem, e a referência `Plan1!$A$1:$A$4` é minha matriz de origem.

> A fórmula descrita no item 3 dará a referência exata de origem ainda que os dados de origem estejam em outra aba/planilha.

Espero ter ajudado!